# How to get data from an object in Firebase database?

Tags: javascript, firebase, firebase-realtime-database

I have the following structure on my firebase database ,
**what i want is that when ever user clicks on submit , it retrieves all the ads with that specified category value since i have pushed category(option) value to  fire base database i.e 1,2,3,4.**

Fire base structure:

[image]

and my html code is :

```
<form class=" jumbotron browseCategory bs1">
    <h3 class="catSearch">SEARCH ADS USING CATEGORY SEARCH</h3> <br/> <hr/>
        <div class="form-group">
                    <label for="formGroupExampleInput2"> Select your category : </label>
                <select id="myselect">
                    <option value="1">Mobile</option>
                    <option value="2">Electronics</option>
                    <option value="3">Property</option>
                    <option value="4">Cosmetics</option>
                  </select> </div>
 <button type="submit" class="btn btn-primary" id="submission_cat">Search Ad of this Category</button>
    </form>
```

Comment: Hi, welcome to stack overflow. Please refer the [ask] link for 
more details on how to ask a question and update your question accordingly.

Comment: @JeroenHeier for sure :')

Comment: Are you using the REST API, or a Realtime Database connection in your javascript?

Comment: @ChristianScillitoe Realtime Database connection

Comment: Can you share what you currently have in your onSubmit() function?

Comment: var catSearch = document.getElementById('gettingCategory'); catSearch.addEventListener('click', e => { let ref = firebase.database().ref("ADS"); ref.orderByChild("adCategory").equalTo(1).on("child_added", function(snapshot) { console.log(snapshot.key); }); });

Answer (score 0, accepted):

To filter ads by adCategory you may use:

```
  let ref = firebase.database().ref("ADS");
    ref.orderByChild("adCategory").equalTo("1").on("child_added", function(snapshot) {  
    console.log(snapshot.key);
    });
```

and hook it up to your submit handler function

Comment: I've hooked this up with my submit handler function but this isn't getting any key on my console neither does it through's any error.

Comment: please post your submit handler and the way you attached this firebase query

Comment: The adCategory is a string in the database, not an integer.

Comment: @AndréKool was right , adCategory was string in database , i replaced int with string one and it's working now . Thankyou all for helping me out :')